# Use enums to restrict multiple object porperties of the type string

Tags: typescript, types, enums, interface, nestjs

I am trying to use enums to restrict some properties of an object called JobOffers as it follows:

/seiority_levels.d.ts

```
export enum seniority {
   JUNIOR = "Júnior",
   MIDLEVEL = "Midlevel"
   SENIOR = "Senior",
   TECNICIAN = "Tecnician",
   TRAINEE = "Trainee",
   ESPECIALIST = "Especialist",
}

export interface ISeniority {
   seniority: SeniorityLevels
}
```

/work_schedule_type.d.ts

```
export enum WorkScheduleTypes {
   FullTime = 'Full-Time',
   PartTime = 'Part-Time',
   Flexible = 'Flexible' | 'Flexible Hours',
   Other = 'Other',
}

export interface IWorkScheduleType {
    workScheduleType: WorkScheduleTypes
}
```

I would like my object to have among other properties the following:

/job_offers.ts

```
import { ISeniority, seniority  } from "interafces/seniority_levels";
import { IWorkScheduleType } from "interafces/work_schedule_type";
import { IStatus } from "interafces/status";

export class JobOffers implements ISeniority, IWorkScheduleType {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    seniority: ISeniority;
    workScheduleType: IWorkScheduleType;
    openSince: Date;
    details?: string;
}
```

As seen above, I am trying to restrict both properties "seniority" and "workScheduleType" to the values present on my enums.

However, when trying to initialize those values, I receive a type error ts(2322).

```
job_offers: JobOffers[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Data Engineering Specialist",
        seniority: "Specialist",
        workScheduleType: "Full-time",
        openSince: new Date()
    },
];
```

The closest I've got this to work was string enumeration like this:

```
export type WorkScheduleTypes =
   'Full-Time'
   | 'Part-Time'
   | 'Flexible' | 'Flexible Hours'
   | 'Other';
```

However, I would like to benefit from using it the other way. Any idea of why this is happening and how to improve it?

Be nice ;)

Comment: If you define an `enum`, why not use it as such, e.g.: `seniority: SeniorityLevels.MIDLEVEL`?

Comment: So I would have to import the enum on every file I would initialize those values?

Comment: Yes of course. You have it marked as `export` anyway.

Comment: I'm a little bit new to this, so if this is the purpose of using it, I'm not sure that's the way I want to proceed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I just saw I could benefit using enums like this, but I thought it was more when I needed to compare values on conditionals. I think this way the code can become a little too coupled. Think I'll stick the usual way.